# Indeterminate JProgressBar Not displaying String

Tags: java, jprogressbar

I am making a virus scanning program (Starting making one) but I set the JProgressBar to indeterminate mode, and the setString(String str) method does not display a string. If I do not use an indeterminate progress bar, the String displays fine.

**EDIT:**
Some code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class Testthing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
        bar.setStringPainted(true);
        bar.setString("Testing");
        frame.add(bar);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This code creates the following frame:
[image: Frame image]

Comment: @AndreDuarte There you go!

Comment: The code you provided works on my machine, what operating system, jdk vendor and version are you running.

Comment: I am running Mac OSX Maverics Java Version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode).

Comment: @pfranza java.vendor = Oracle Corporation

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Java progress bar on Mac OS X doesn't support displaying the string for indeterminate progress bars. The behavior on my system is the same. Mac OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember to set `setStringPainted(true)` to true.  [The default value is false](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setStringPainted(boolean))

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class ProgressBar {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressBar.setString("Loading...");
    // This is the important line 
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);


    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.add(progressBar);
    f.pack();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```